# Python List losing values while still in scope

Tags: python, list, scope

Please look at the following code snippet written in python

```
import os

my_files = []
FOLDER_PATH = r'PATH_To_FOLDER'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(FOLDER_PATH):
    #print(root)
    my_files = [root +'\\'+ f for f in files if f.endswith('.txt')]
    print(my_files[:]) #files are there in my_files
    #print(len(my_files)) #outputs 2

for f in my_files: #len(my_files) = 0 at this point, why?
    with open(f,'r') as ff:
    print(ff.read())
```

while it's obvious that my_files is still in scope, it should retain it's values. But it simply doesn't?

Comment: but on each iteration you assign it to a new list, perhaps you meant to use `list.extend`? If the final iteration yields an empty list that would explain why its empty.

Comment: If Paul's interpretation is correct, this can be fixed by simply changing your `=` to a `+=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `list.extend` to add the content of one list to another list.

Presently you just reassign to the same list variable on each iteration, so if it's empty it only means that the last iteration of `os.walk` returned no files. The fact of it being in scope or not makes no difference, if you are periodically changing to what it refers.

```
from os import walk, path

my_files = []
FOLDER_PATH = r'.'
for root, dirs, files in walk(FOLDER_PATH):
    my_files.extend(path.join(root, f) for f in files if f.endswith('.txt'))

print(my_files)

for f in my_files:
    print('**** %s' % f)
    with open(f,'r') as ff:
        print(ff.read())
```

Also using `os.path.join` will give you platform independent path creation.

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension; drop the `[` and `]` and make it a generator expression.

Comment: And note that replacing `=` with `+=` in the original would have worked too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks thats a worthwhile change, given we don't know how many files there might be.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension creates a *new list*, and you reassign your variable to address that new list. This is very much like doing:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a = [4, 5, 6]
```

And expecting:

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Instead, you want to append all of the new values onto the existing list, using the `extend` method or `+=`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.extend([4, 5, 6])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In your case, that will look like this (noting that you can remove the `[]` from the list comprehension to turn it into a *generator expression*, which makes very little difference in this case except to make the code a little more readable):

```
my_files.extend(root +'\\'+ f for f in files if f.endswith('.txt'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **list.extend**.

What you are doing is reassigning list (my_files list in your case). so In every loop its value is reassigned instead of adding to existing list. This is where list.extend comes.

```
my_files = []
    FOLDER_PATH = r'abc'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(FOLDER_PATH):
        my_files.extend(root +'/'+ f for f in files if f.endswith('.txt'))

    for f in my_files: #len(my_files) = 0 at this point, why?
        with open(f,'r') as ff:
            print(ff.read())
```